# Refile gem ImageMagick error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, refile

Using Refile gem to upload messages in my app to s3. My server is Ubuntu 16 and I am using Capistano and Nginx for deployment and server. Not sure why this error is coming up in production, but I am having trouble retrieving images in production from s3. It works fine in Dev, but in production, the images upload fine and I can see them in my s3 bucket, but they do not display when I try to retrieve them. The error message I get in the log files is:

`Refile::App: Error -> ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed`

I have installed `imagemagick` and `graphicsmagick` on my server but no change. Is anyone else having this issue and what could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

**This must solve your problem**

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

if still problem exists this may work [Click to go to documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471045/14-04-doesnt-have-package-imagemagick)

Comment: I have used this command before posting the issue and it didnt solve the problem. I even removed and reinstalled imagemagick but no way!